# error when use array wchar

Tags: c, arrays, wchar

I have a variable with type wchar (szDrive), now i want to have a array and element of it has type wchar.
Here is some my code:

```
typedef struct array_wchar{
WCHAR array_char[5];
};
array_wchar array_driveName0[10];
int array_driveName_index0 =0;
WCHAR szDrive[5] = L" :\\";
```

but when i write:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    array_driveName1[i].array_char = szDrive;
}
```

it has an error: `error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value`

Can someone explain me why and can give resolution? plz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign directly to an array like that. You need to either use memcpy / strcpy or assign to individual elements:

```
memcpy(array_driveName0[i].array_char, szDrive, sizeof(array_driveName0[i].array_char));
```

or

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    array_driveName0[i].array_char[j] = szDrive[j];
}
```

Also you seem to be referencing array_driveName1 where you have only declared array_driveName0.

Your overall structure is very confusing. You have an array of structs, each of which contains only an array of WCHARs - why not just have an array of arrays and remove the struct entirely?

For example:

```
typedef WCHAR array_char_t[5];
array_char_t array_driveName0[10];
WCHAR szDrive[5] = L" :\\";

memcpy(array_driveName0[i], szDrive, sizeof(array_driveName0[i]));
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's resolved my problem :). i don't understand your mind, what does it mean? can you give example for it?

Comment: I'm glad it's helped - please consider up-voting and/or accepting the answer. I've edited it to add an example on the last part which I assume is what you didn't understand.